# MySQL WHERE condition to select all records from start of the hour

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause

```
WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

The above query works fine to get data that belongs to last 1 HOUR. Let's say I run the query at 2020-10-15 18:08:00. It will give me all the records between the below time period.

```
2020-10-15 17:08:00 - 2020-10-15 18:08:00
```

I have been trying to create a mysql query to get data from the beginning of the hour. Let's again say I ran the query at 2020-10-15 18:08:00. I need a query to get me the results belonging the below time period.

```
2020-10-15 18:00:00 - 2020-10-15 18:08:00
```

I would appreciate some feedback on this.

Answer (score 2):

In many databases (as Postgres for example), you can do this with `date_trunc()`, or the-like (in Oracle: `trunc()`).

Unfortunately MySQL does not implement this function - however it is flexible enough to understand dates as strings. I like to use `date_format` for this:

```
where timestamp >= date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried above, but it did not work.

Comment: @Mr.Eboy: please run the query exactly as provided. This works as intended, as you can see [in this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a7cf2b8b697854d56e6d5f9d36d9265)

Comment: I am very sorry. I had done a syntax mistake. It works now. Truely appriciate it. Thank you very much.